# Intergrating AEM/CQ5 and Spring Framework?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aem, aem-6

I have been trying to integrate Spring framework within AEM6/CQ5.

I am following this tutorial. [LINK](http://neba.io/userguide.html)

As per the tutorial I have installed the NEBA package.
All NEBA bundles are active in OSGi console.

Then I created my own Maven CQ5 project, I added the dependencies of Neba annotations and Spring. My project was also successfully deployed in CQ5(bundle is active).

I tried to use a ResourceModel annotation of NEBA. But this model does not appear in the model registry of NEBA.
I mapped the ResourceModel to a content component that i created "linkComponent".

When the user drags and drops this on any parsys the resource node has the properties **linkName** and **linkURL**.

I tried accessing these values in JSP but I failed.

Please See code below :
    package com.zensar.neba;

```
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;

import io.neba.api.annotations.Path;
import io.neba.api.annotations.ResourceModel;

@ResourceModel(types = "zensar-neba/components/content/linkComponent")
public class LinkComponent {

    private String linkName;
    private String linkURL;

    public String getLinkName() {
        return linkName;
    }
    public void setLinkName(String linkName) {
        this.linkName = linkName;
    }
    public String getLinkURL() {
        return linkURL;
    }
    public void setLinkURL(String linkURL) {
        this.linkURL = linkURL;
    }


}
```

Please See JSP Code of *linkComponent* below:

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
<%@taglib prefix="neba" uri="http://neba.io/1.0"%>
<neba:defineObjects />
Link Component
<a href="${m.linkURL}"> Click Here ${m.linkName}</a>
```

Then I tried creating an **Controller** using **Spring annotation** but I got **"Path not found"** what am I missing.

Please see code below:

```
package com.zensar.neba;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class DemoController {
    @RequestMapping("/echo/{param}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String echo(@PathVariable("param") String paramToEcho) {
       return "Hello "+ paramToEcho;
    }
}
```

I called the controller link this : ***http://localhost:4502/bin/mvc.do/echo/Oliver***

**IMPORTANT NOTE:
All my bundles are active**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all bundles are up and running and you are seeing the model registry, it means everything is running smoothly. But: your model doesn't show up, this means that the application context of your bundle isn't running. NEBA uses gemini-blueprint, the reference implementation of the OSGi blueprint specification.

Do you have an xml file, e.g. blueprint.xml, in the OSGI-INF/blueprint folder of your bundle? It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:bp="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
   http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.zensar.neba" />
</beans>
```

If you do, what does your error.log say when your bundle is starting?
For reference, here is a sample webapp using NEBA: https://github.com/unic/publication-neba-adaptto-2015

One more thing: NEBA uses private field injection, so you don't need to have any setters on your bean.

Comment: Hi @Olaf I dont have this xml file. can you tell me where to place this file in my CQ5 Maven Project.

Comment: If I had a hundred million dollars I would them to you. I added the context.xml and everything worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad to have helped! Just to answer your last question: In a maven project, the right location for the blueprint XML file would be in the src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint folder of the maven module containing your models / controllers.